# Retain KDB Long Epoch Time When Importing Into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, kdb, epoch, pyq

I have epoch times from KDB e.g. **530782044475144833**. But any data type I have used in Pandas e.g. int, float64 severely round it up to **5.31e+17**, rendering it useless. How do I retain the entire length of the KDB epoch time when reading into Pandas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One solution could be to store only the offset from a baseline and not the entire epoch time.

Comment: Have you tried `np.int64`?

Comment: @chrisaycock -- Thanks Chris. Using np.int64 returns "TypeError: data type "np.int64" not understood". Using just int64 returns "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'5.31E+17'".

Comment: Thanks Joao -- That seems to be a feasible workaround.

Comment: @skafetaur I assume the "TypeError: data type "np.int64" not understood" is coming from whatever KDB adapter you're using. The adapter itself needs to be able to convert `j` types properly.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent (> 4.0) versions of [PyQ](https://pyq.enlnt.com), kdb+ timestamp vectors can be easily converted to numpy arrays. For example:

```
>>> p = q('2#.z.P')
>>> p
k('2017.07.05D13:37:41.058130000 2017.07.05D13:37:41.058130000')
>>> p.long
k('552577061058130000 552577061058130000')
>>> a = np.array(p)
>>> a
array(['2017-07-05T13:37:41.058130000', '2017-07-05T13:37:41.058130000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

This does an automatic epoch conversion and does not loose any precision

```
>>> p == a
True
```

The resulting array can be cast into a panda's `DatetimeIndex`:

```
>>> pd.DatetimeIndex(a)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-07-05 13:37:41.058130', '2017-07-05 13:37:41.058130'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

or placed in a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':a})
                   timestamp
0 2017-07-05 13:37:41.058130
1 2017-07-05 13:37:41.058130
```